# Microsoft Sync Framework Header Detail Tables

Tags: frameworks, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have Header and detail tables using identity column as the foreign key. When synchronizing among clients and server is there a way to obtain header identity column value from server and update it in the detail table on server. I'm trying to remove duplication error in server and clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'll avoid using identity columns in synchronization... if you're altering keys to avoid PK collissions then you'll have another issue of making sure you cascade the same changes on all replicas.

have a look a these blog posts on some workarounds around PKs in Sync Framework:

[Upload synchronization Where the client and server primary keys are different](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/upload-synchronization-where-the-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)

[part 2 bidirectional synchronization where the client and server primary keys are different](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/part-2-bidirectional-synchronization-where-the-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)

[part 3 synchronizing tables where client and server primary keys are different](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/part-3-synchronizing-tables-where-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)

Comment: Thank you, That was really helpful I have came across with using a guid for primary from the same blog you mentioned. But the problem is my system is existing system and currently we have lot of reports using the Identity column as a join column. I'm looking for a workaround to avoid the entire program changing.

Comment: let's say you have OrderId =1 and OrderDetailIdFK = 1 from ClientX, now your server already has OrderId 1 from clientA, so you now want to update the second OrderId =1 from ClientX to OrderId=2, how do you track now that OrderId = 2 is originally OrderId =1 from ClientX? if you're doing bidirectional sync, that's an even bigger issue.

Comment: I have some other unique columns maintained to find records. What you have explained is what i want to do.No its only update from client.